# Uncaught No Chrome Web Store item link found. in Meteor App

Tags: meteor, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting the following error Uncaught No Chrome Web Store item link found.

I have the link tag installed my in header app as required

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ighphffjhlbfaomehoboceklndcfknfh">

<div class="hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"><a style="margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 15px" href="#" onclick="chrome.webstore.install()"  class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right">Linkly Chrome Extension</a></div>
```

You can see the issue at https://linklyapp.com

Answer (score 0):

the error actually explains itself pretty well it can't find

`<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ighphffjhlbfaomehoboceklndcfknfh">`

in the source code. So it's probably missing. How do you add it to the head? If you need to edit the head you just need to add `<head>code here</head>` in your meteor html files.

Comment: it's add in the head you can see it by doing a view source

Comment: @AlmogKoren now It seems to be in the head I didn't see it before. Also it seems to be non meteor problem here is the guide on how to setup the link correctly: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

Comment: what are you talking about it needs to be in the head

"The HTML page on your site from which you want inline installation to occur must contain one or more <link> tags in the <head> section"